# Efficiently store arrays of probability values as .npy

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple entries in the form of:

```
{'sample':a ,'vector': array[0.0000001, 0., 0., 0., .... 0.000123, 0.]}
```

I save these to a .npy file using dtype=np.float64 for the array of probability values and the file size of the resulting .npy file becomes immensely big.

Is there a way to reduce the file size? Are there other dtypes that make sense in a probability value setting? (my probability vectors have varying lengths)

Comment: It all depends on the meaning of these probabilities: how have they been established and how are they used? 64-bit float is almost certainly overkill for probabilities. The other thought is that if you can transform your dict into e.g. a Pandas DataFrame, you could save it in parquet format, which has nice compression options.

Comment: While a `npy` of a `dict` involves an added layer of 'pickle', the file size won't be much different from saving the array directly.  And  file size is roughly the same as the array size, e.g. `adict['vector'].nbytes`.

Comment: if there are a lot of 0's in these vectors then maybe a sparse array approach could help.